# How do I get my debugger past the "TraceOverConditional mod.user(cip)" is debug-only message?

Tags: assembly, masm32

I am currently learning MASM and GoASM using the EasyCode IDE and have x32dbg and x64dbgs set up respectively for both kind of assembler languages.

When I build and link a MASM file like so, nothing is wrong and the build finished with no errors like so:

### The MASM code:

```
.Const
trouble EQU 0ABADDEEDh
.Data?

.Data

hinst       HINSTANCE   NULL
buffer   db 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'
bword   dw 25
bdouble dd 0DEADBEEFh

.Code

start:
    Invoke GetModuleHandle, NULL
    Mov hinst, Eax
    ;=====================
    ; Write your code here
    ;=====================
    mov al,[buffer]
    mov al,[buffer+1]
    mov ax,bword
    mov eax, bdouble
    mov eax, trouble
    mov bdouble, eax

    Invoke ExitProcess, 0
End start
```

### The Results of building and linking:

> ============== Project1 - Debug (Press  to cancel) ==============
>
> Assembling: Project1
>
> Linking...
>
> Project1.exe - No error
>
> 10110 bytes

### The debugger and debugger log

However, when I attempt to start my debugger, I get a blank debugger screen like so:
[image]

Pressing the "Run to user code" button (the arrow pointing to the person's head icon in the top bar) does not trigger any instruction set dump and rather keeps appending this error message to the debug log as shown below:

```
Initializing wait objects...
Initializing debugger...
Initializing debugger functions...
Setting JSON memory management functions...
Initializing Zydis...
Getting directory information...
Start file read thread...
Retrieving syscall indices...
Symbol Path: C:\UserData\z0049zfs\Documents\Onboard Documents\Onboard Software Tools\Assembler stuff\release\x32\symbols
Allocating message stack...
Initializing global script variables...
Registering debugger commands...
Registering GUI command handler...
Registering expression functions...
Registering format functions...
Registering Script DLL command handler...
Starting command loop...
Initialization successful!
Loading plugins...
Handling command line...
  "C:\Documents\Local Documents\Software Tools\Assembler stuff\release\x32\x32dbg.exe" C:\Documents\Local Documents\Software Tools\Assembler stuff\EasyCodeProjects\Project1\Debug\Project1.exe
Syscall indices loaded!
Error codes database loaded!
Exception codes database loaded!
NTSTATUS codes database loaded!
Windows constant database loaded!
Reading notes file...
File read thread finished!
The command "TraceOverConditional mod.user(cip)" is debug-only <--- The error message that keeps appending
The command "TraceOverConditional mod.user(cip)" is debug-only
The command "TraceOverConditional mod.user(cip)" is debug-only
```

## Question

How do I get my debugger to, you know, debug and not have this message appear?